# Sliding input box to the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css, jsx

I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks on the input box, it will glide to the bottom of the screen, but with the way I have it implemented right now, it moves too far down and you have to scroll down on the page to actually see the input box.

Code for the page:

```
'use client';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Header from '@/components/Header';
import SendChatButton from '@/components/buttons/SendChatButton';

export default function Home() {
  const [isInputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  const [formHeight, setFormHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      setFormHeight(formRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }
  }, []);

  const formStyle = isInputFocused
    ? { transform: `translateY(calc(100vh - ${formHeight}px))` }
    : {};

  return (
    <main>
      <section className='p-4 pt-32'>
        <div>
          <h1 className='text-6xl font-bold'>
            Your very own<br /> personal designer
          </h1>
          <h2 className='text-xl mt-6'>Makes finding outfits so much easier</h2>
        </div>
        <form 
          ref={formRef}
          style={formStyle}
          className="mt-6 flex shadow-md transition-transform duration-1000 ease-in-out"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder='Message your personal designer...'
            className="p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md block w-full text-sm outline-none"
            onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
            onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
          />
          <SendChatButton />
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're having it move down 100vh from its current position on the page. If you want it to go down to the bottom of the screen and stay there as you scroll, you need `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that calculating the new form height based on the `100vh` does not consider the rest of the elements on the page. If your page only had the form alone, this would work. But currently, there are other elements, therefore the `100vh - ${formHeight}px` is added from the top position of where the form currently is, and not from the top of your page. Hope that makes sense.

A nifty workaround would be to make the `section initially` occupy the entire `100vh`. Then make it so that the form's height is all remaining space of the `section`. On `focus`, change the height of the form to some value (since changing to `auto` will not add the animation aspect to it).

This is what I have come up with:

```
'use client';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Header from '@/components/Header';
import SendChatButton from '@/components/buttons/SendChatButton';

export default function Home() {
  const [isInputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  const [formHeight, setFormHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      setFormHeight(formRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }
  }, []);

  //   added this to make the form grow when focused
  const formStyle = isInputFocused ? { height: '3rem' } : {};

  return (
    <main>
      {/* added flex and justify-between to make the form stick to the bottom */}
      <section className="p-4 pt-32 bg-red-300 h-screen flex flex-col justify-between">
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold">
            Your very own
            <br /> personal designer
          </h1>
          <h2 className="text-xl mt-6">Makes finding outfits so much easier</h2>
        </div>
        <form
          ref={formRef}
          style={formStyle}
          // and added transition to make it smooth, with h-full, which will be overridden by the formStyle
          className="mt-6 flex shadow-md duration-1000 ease-in-out bg-green-300 transition-all h-full"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Message your personal designer..."
            className="p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md block w-full text-sm outline-none h-min"
            onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
            onBlur={() => setInputFocused(false)}
          />
          <SendChatButton />
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Hope it helps.